# How to run some script inside Docker Container?

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile

I have few git repos which are required to build application. I have written one Dockerfile to clone the repo,checkout to development branch and run commands to build the application. I am able to build the docker image properly with this dockerfile. But now i want to use some shell script "update.sh" since i have multiple git repos to update inside the dockerfile, such that code should be updated and build will be made on the updated code. I have tried to keep the same in Dockerfile, but it is not updating everytime, first time it has updated, and from next time it is taking that image from cache.

Infrastructure Details:
I have 8 git repos as below:

```
A-->B-->C-->D and so on
```

I have made one script to clone & update other repositories and kept inside A.
Issue is when i am running the script, first time it is running, but from next time it is taking the things from cache.

Could someone help me in getting it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled and found solution [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1996#issuecomment-172606763). It worked for me.

```
FROM foo
ARG CACHE_DATE=2016-01-01
RUN git clone ...
docker build --build-arg CACHE_DATE=$(date) ....
```

Answer (score 0):

you can build you Dockerfile with:

```
docker build --no-cache
```

to avoid your cache issue.

Comment: then i guess it will run each step freshly, it will be like running Dockerfile freshly. I would like to have something incrementally.

Comment: @love i dont know your infrastructure but would it be possible to mount your git folders and refresh them outside of docker?

Comment: is storing the script in a volume an option? that way you isolate them from the build process

Comment: @Gabbax0r I have updated the infra details. I am newbie to docker. Could you please explain the mounting the repos outside docker option.
Thanks!!

Comment: Simply have repos outside docker, clone them from inside with tag or something like that, to act in behalf of versioning. 
@Gabbax0r But I'm no expert, is this what you mean?